# Confusion in translating quantified statements in English to symbolic logic

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers, word-problem, logic-translation

Normally, I don't face difficulties in translating quantified statements in English to symbolic logic, but here I need advice. Thanks in advance!

> **Domain:**

A set of employees who work at a company. Ingrid is one of the employees at the company.

- $S(x)$: $x$ was sick yesterday
- $W(x)$: $x$ went to work yesterday
- $V(x)$: $x$ went on vacation yesterday

**1)** Someone besides Ingrid was sick yesterday.
**A.** ∃x S(x) ∧ x ≠ Ingrid    .....if this is correct then it doesn't talk about what if Ingrid was sick as there is a possibility of both he was sick or not.

**2)** Everyone besides Ingrid was sick yesterday.
**A.** ∀x S(x) ∧ x ≠ Ingrid .......same problem here also like mentioned for above one.

**3)** Someone who missed work was neither sick nor on vacation.
**A.** ∃x [ ¬W(x) → ¬ S(x) ∧ ¬ V(x) ] ....... Is it correct? I think it is.

Comment: 1) is fine. For 2) : $\forall x (x \ne Ingrid \to S(x))$.

Comment: In general, $\exists$ needs $\land$ while $\forall$ needs $\to$. See [bounded quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)#Equivalent_expressions).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I also heard that so it means the third one is wrong even though it has who involved? And should be like this ∃x [ ¬W(x) ∧ ¬ S(x) ∧ ¬ V(x) ] Is it correct? Thank-you!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, now I think it is not always the case that → must be used with ∀, For example, see one question here **Domain:** A set of fourth graders at Lee Elementary School. **P(x):** x took the math test **Q(x):** x is present today. **Question:** Every student was present and took the math test. **Correct Answer:** ∀x (Q(x) ∧ P(x)) **Wrong Answer:** ∀x (Q(x) → P(x)) What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: I agree... but we can say also: $\forall x (Student(x) \to (Present(x) \land Took(x)))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Someone besides Ingrid was sick yesterday.

You are (mostly) correct, but you'll need to use parentheses to indicate the **scope** of the quantifier "$\exists$" in this case. $\exists x(\langle \text{whatever you need to say about} x\rangle).$

(The same is true when you are addressing anything about "all": $\forall x(\langle \text{whatever you need to say about} x \rangle).$ Remember to use parenthes!)

So, we simply modify your answer. Then we have $$\exists x (S(x) \land (x\neq \text{Ingrid}))\tag{1}$$

**2)** Everyone besides Ingrid was sick yesterday.

$$\forall x((x\neq \text{Ingrid})\rightarrow S(x))\tag{2}$$

**3)** Someone who missed work was neither sick nor on vacation.
$$∃x (\lnot W(x) \land ¬ S(x) \land ¬ V(x))\tag{3}$$

As Mauro indicated in the comments, when we use $\forall$, you can expect to use implication ($\rightarrow$).  And when we use $\exists,$ you can expect to use conjuction ($\land$).

Comment: Yeah! but your last point, I think it is not always the case, For example, see one question here **Domain:** A set of fourth graders at Lee Elementary School. **P(x):** x took the math test **Q(x):** x is present today. **Question:** Every student was present and took the math test. **Correct Answer:** ∀x (Q(x) ∧ P(x)) **Wrong Answer:**  ∀x (Q(x) →  P(x)) What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, $\forall x (Q(x) \rightarrow P(x))$ is correct.  Perhaps there exists 4th grade student(s) of Lee Elementary who weren't present$. Your statement would then be false, because it claims all students are present, and all students took the math test.  Instead, we can say: For all x, (if x was present, then x took the math text).  So we are not making any claim about those who may have not been present.  And my last sentence means only that generally speaking, we can usually expect implication with the universal, and conjunction with the existential.

Comment: I also think it should be like this straight forward. So, it means that book is wrong where it is written like this by the author.

Comment: There may be exceptions to the rule...but rarely so.  If in fact it is known that all 4th grade students *were* present, and it is also known that all fourth grade students took the math test, then $\forall x(Q(x) \land P(x)) would be true.  Though, the implication would not be wrong.